# If this (mostly copied) answer was rightfully deleted, how should one refer to another answer to another question?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, moderators

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42953345/1446005) has been deleted.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42953345/1446005

Formally, it seems to be a valid answer. I believe the technical (in)validity of the answer should be irrelevant here (I base my opinion on the fact that several of my flags have been declined with "flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer").

Perhaps it was judged plagiarism since 90% of the post is a verbatim copy of another answer? (although I reckon authorship was properly attributed).

I suspect the author of the question may have flagged the answer as NAA. If it were the case, would you agree that this is Not An Answer?

Reading the [documented reasons for closure](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers), the closest reason that may remotely apply to this case is:

> Answers [...] that are: 
>   [...]
>   * exact duplicates of other answers
>   [...]

**I believe this should be undestood as "duplicates of other answers *to the same question*". If not, please suggest a better alternative, when an existing answer to *another* question may answer the *current* question.**

Please disregard that I was the author of the answer, as well as the heated argument that took place in the comments. This may need to be addressed too, but elsewhere.

I added the [moderator] tag because I would love to hear from the moderator who closed the post.

The answer is reproduced below for those who may not access deleted content.

---

> [alex's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5239747/1446005) worked perfectly fine for me (FF v52.0.1-x64), and I didn't have to mess with Firefox internals :
>
> > Ok, after 10 minutes of wtf'ing, the easy way to fix it is close to
> >     that of lineofbirds
> >
> > 1. Type in www.yoursite.com/favicon.ico (or www.yoursite.com/apple-touch-icon.png, etc.)
> > 2. Push <kbd>enter</kbd>
> > 3. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f5</kbd>
> > 4. Restart Browser (IE, Firefox)
>
> Yes, it's a pity.

---

Comment: Also, sorry for the twisted title, the system won't let me use the title "Why was the question deleted", which it deems too generic. Any advice on this issue is welcome.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was flagged by the OP of the Question as not an answer as indicated by the comments of said OP.

Comment: @rene And would you agree that this is NAA? This is the point of my question, I have rephrased.

Comment: It is not NAA enough to survive the queue but the answer isn't needed as it doesn't bring anything new to the table. I wait for a moderator to explain what flag they responded to.

Comment: Eww on that revision list. The OP really REALLY wants to keep some of the junkier parts of his question

Comment: The post was brought to my attention by a comment flag. Since it was negatively scored, the bulk of it consists of a link to and the content of another post, and seemed to be a source for debate it made sense to delete the post -- it'd be better posted as a comment.

Comment: ...for your "alternative"... It's called closing as duplicate. If you uave an answer elsewhere, you close as duplicate so ppl can follow the trail to the right answer.

Comment: It's simply a copy of one of the other answers with the text "it worked for me added". What value do you think that has?

Comment: Thank you @JonClements for the feedback. I take note that a comment is the recommended choice in such a case (although I disagree, but this is another story).

Comment: @Patrice As I advised in the deleted comments, I was reluctant to closing as dupe, because the *question* was sensibly different ("favicon not displayed by Firefox" vs "How do I force a favicon refresh"). It happens that the same action fixed the issue. Would you vote for closing the question as duplicate?

Comment: @RobertLongson This question is one of the first ones that I quickly stumbled upon when I had the issue (and I observed the exact same behaviour as what the OP described, despite his not believing me). The solution that I reproduced, which I found after some longer research, did fix my issue. What would you recommend instead?

Comment: @RandomSeed considering this is EXACTLY the use case for duplicates.... Yes. Dupes aren't for "you have the same issue word for word". It is more for "the issue you have has the same fix as this one".

Comment: @RobertLongson Please note that this is a copy of another answer to *another question*.

Comment: Then vote to close as a duplicate if answers to this question, answer that one.

Comment: @Patrice and Robert, I have neither the expertise to know for sure, nor the time to investigate, that this answer (or the other answers to the other question) fixes the issue in all cases. Would you also vote to close as dupe? If not, should I just have kept my mouth shut and keep the (possible) solution to myself?

Comment: You have the rep to comment, why didn't you do that and simply suggest that the other question and it's answers might be helpful? Others could then have used that to vote on duplication.

Comment: @RobertLongson You seem to agree with Jon who deleted the answer. I disagree, I believe answers (even possible ones) should not appear in comments but as, well, answers. However this approach seems to be the consensus, therefore I rest my case. If you could post this as an answer I will accept it. If you do not wish to spend more time on the matter, I will write the answer myself.

Comment: I wonder why so many downvotes on the question, and so many upvotes on the answer :)

Comment: @RandomSeed disagreement with the premise of the question, agreement with the answer.

Comment: Yes Gimby, I always forget that downvotes on Meta means more "disagree" than "useless question".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If an answer to another question does indeed answer the current question, then vote to close one of them as duplicate.

If you are unsure that the questions are similar enough to be duplicates, then just link to the other answer in a comment. Then the other question is likely to show up in the "Linked" section.

Do not duplicate information.